# Images won't load after build when using React with Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, create-react-app

I'm developing an app using React and Electron.

I'm storing the images  in `src/assets/images`. When I run the app in development using `react-scripts start` and `electron .` everything works fine.

The problem occurs when the react app is built using `react-scripts build`. When the first view is loaded the path is correctly resolved, for example `file:///D:/Projects/app-name/build/static/media/logo.e99ed458.png` and the image is displayed.

Now, when the route changes, the image no longer works. In the network tab in devTools the request URL is `file:///D:/main/static/media/logo.e99ed458.png` which is obviously incorrect.

This is my component code:

```
import React from "react";
import Logo from '../../assets/images/ad.png';

const Logo = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <img src={Logo} alt="no image" />
        </React.Fragment >
    );
};

export default Logo;
```

And in `electron.js`

```
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true,
    pathname: require('path').join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')
}));
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for two days now. Does anyone know a solution?

EDIT:

I have also tried using PUBLIC_URL according to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

But the result is the same, the path is resolved correctly when the first view is displayed and after that it resolves to `file:///D:/assets/images/logo.png`.

When I log `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` it says that PUBLIC_URL is equal to ".".

Comment: This is not a very straight forward process. Please review: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c/ as it has been done before. Have you tried following any guides that specifically accomplish this? I will work on a test demo to help answer this.

Comment: Yes, I have followed more than a few guides. Also I've read the link you posted and my code looks the same.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by changing the routers instead of using `BrowserRouter` you should use `HashRouter`

This article https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c/  has a good example but Does not have the configurations of routers